# PHP / Python Check if firewall is turned off

Tags: php, python, html, cmd, firewall

is it possible to write a PHP script that checks if the PC's firewall is disabled and then output yes/no into a checkbox on the webpage? (Hosting my own web server using WAMP)

Currently what i have in mind is create a .bat file that checks if firewall is turned off
using:

```
netsh advfirewall show public
```

then check if the State shown on CMD is On / OFF and return results to the web-page's checkbox. 
Thing is i have no idea how do i go about doing the check state and return results.

Please advise. Also open to other ideas / solutions that could provide similar results.

PS: Am a beginner at PHP scripting and only started learning python today and project is due in 3 weeks. Also would be nice if you could link full code solutions if you know of any. I learn faster through referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get only the status of the public profile :

> "netsh advfirewall show public state"

This command can be used in a python script with the subprocess module :

`result = subprocess.check_output(["netsh", "advfirewall", "show ", "allprofiles", "state"].decode('utf-8')`

The result will be a string, using regex you will be able to get the value from it.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Example of regex :

```
status = re.search('state[ ]*([A-Za-z])*', result).group(1)
```